# Adding a Column to Spark Table via SQL ALTER TABLE command

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, alter-table

Can I add a new column to an existing spark table using the ALTER TABLE command ?

```
var query = "ALTER TABLE " + "global_temp." + tableName(0) + " ADD COLUMN " + newColumnName + " " + newColumnDatatype
var drt = spark.sql(query)
```

The above code raises the following error.

```
 no viable alternative at input 'ALTER TABLE global_temp.people_ty ADD COLUMN' new_age integer
```

**EDIT**

The correct syntax is as follows

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMNS (newColumn newDataType)
```

But, it also throws the following error.

```
ALTER ADD COLUMNS does not support views.
You must drop and re-create the views for adding the new columns. Views: `global_temp`.`people_ty`
```

Comment: Is `people_ty` registered using `createOrReplaceTempView`?

Comment: Data frames are immutable, you cannot alter them.

Comment: @philantrovert , people_ty is registered using createGlobalTempView

Comment: Why not do a `withColumn` before you create a view out of it?

Comment: Yes, that is an alternative. But, is it possible to do it with an SQL Query ?

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?

According the documentation that should be allowed from spark 2.2

Comment: Spark 2.3.0 . The syntax is ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMNS (newColumn newDataType)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spark SQL the syntax is as mentioned by Soumyadip Ghosh in the comments

```
ALTER TABLE table_identifier ADD COLUMNS ( col_spec [ , ... ] )
```

Works for me.